# AttributeError: module 'django.conf.global_settings' has no attribute 'ROOT_URLCONF'

Tags: django, server, module, attributes

I'm working on PokerAi with my server(Ubuntu),
and i used
https://github.com/datamllab/rlcard
https://github.com/datamllab/rlcard-showdown/
these sources.
I tried to run rlcard-showdown using my domain not localhost, but it got an error.
my django version is 4.2.3 and node version is 20.4.0

Here is my error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 137, in run
    self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 124, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 139, in get_response
    set_urlconf(settings.ROOT_URLCONF)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 104, in __getattr__
    val = getattr(_wrapped, name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 311, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self.default_settings, name)
AttributeError: module 'django.conf.global_settings' has no attribute 'ROOT_URLCONF'
[06/Jul/2023 17:13:06] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 59
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 137, in run
    self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 124, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 139, in get_response
    set_urlconf(settings.ROOT_URLCONF)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 104, in __getattr__
    val = getattr(_wrapped, name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 311, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self.default_settings, name)
AttributeError: module 'django.conf.global_settings' has no attribute 'ROOT_URLCONF'
[06/Jul/2023 17:13:06] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 500 59
```

and my setting.py

```
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))))

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '-t@mf4fi)gfxzv5lm8qkg)*5u^brj--y*ul2&ryqdem(xin8(!'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = TRUE

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['mydomain(i put this)', '000.000.00.00', '000.000.00.00']

# Cors config
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL=True

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'corsheaders',
    'tournament',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'server.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'server.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

help........

Answer (score 0):

module 'django.conf.global_settings' has no value ROOT_URLCONF because your ROOT_URLCONF is being configured incorrectly.

'server.urls' is referencing something that doesn't exist. Try 'server.server.urls', since that's how your project is structured, or move the urls.py file up one level